# Reading appsettings.json key in Entity Framework Core project

Tags: entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I need to read a key (already) defined in Host/MVC [StartUp] project's `appsettings.json` file in my Entity Framework Core project, a code sample would be very helpful.

What I want is, to read a (seed data) json file (path is defined in `appsettings.json`) and use it to load seed data into my entities (reading, parsing and creating entity objects is already done) with hardcoded file path in .cs file. I just want to read file from the path given in `appsettings.json`.

From documentation, I tried

```
var value2 = SettingManager.GetSettingValue("SmtpServerAddress");
```

but I am unable to use it. Do I need to inject something, how can I instantiate `SettingManager` in an Entity Framework Core project?

I am using boilerplate v 6.0.

Thanks.

Comment: Hammad, could you please explain a little about what it means to you to not be able to use it? Is value2 being set?

Comment: No, the line is from the documentation, I can't call SettingManager.GetSettingValue directly in EntityframeworkCore project, if possible how can I inject/call SettingManager here (i.e. other than the startup project?)

Comment: Here's how I did it inside of a Razor page.    @inject IConfiguration Configuration  ... <a class="nav-link text-dark" target="_blank" href="@Configuration["ReportSettings:SystemPermissionsUrl"]">System Permissions</a>

Comment: I should state the the @inject IConfiguration Configuration line was at the top of the page just under my model declaration.

Comment: Actually, I can't inject anything directly because the SeedData call is automatic by AspNetZero